# What is the difference between electromagnetic wave and electromagnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, field-theory, terminology

I am confused about the difference between electromagnetic waves and electromagnetic fields. Can you please explain the distinction between the two and how they relate to each other?

Comment: An electromagnetic wave is the variation of an electromagnetic field over time (and space).

Comment: As an analogy: EM wave is to EM field (roughly) as a water wave is to a surface of a lake.

Answer (score 1):

I would say, an electromagnetic wave is an electromagnetic field that satisfies the wave equation.

Answer (score 1):

An electromagnetic wave is a type of **energy** that **travels** through space, while an electromagnetic field is a physical field that can **exist** in a given point in space.

The electromagnetic wave is created by **oscillating electric and magnetic fields** and the electromagnetic field is created by the movement of charged particles.

Examples of electromagnetic waves include radio waves, microwaves, infrared radiation, visible light, ultraviolet radiation, X-rays, and gamma rays. The electromagnetic field consists of two parts, the electric field and the magnetic field. The electric field is created by the movement of electric charges, and the magnetic field is created by the movement of electric currents.

**In short, you can say that EM wave is EM field traveling (not just existing) in an medium.**